# K-means for 2D point clustering in python

Tags: image-processing, opencv, image-segmentation, python, machine-learning

I have a set of points(2D) whose pixels are set and want to perform k-means on these pixels. Is clustering the 2D coordinates the right way ?

If so, can that be done using any libraries in python ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It can be done very easily with the [**scikit-learn**](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/).  Examples are easy to find on their website, i.e. [**here**](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/cluster/plot_mini_batch_kmeans.html#example-cluster-plot-mini-batch-kmeans-py). In my opinion it is the best way to go.

Modified code example from the above link:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from sklearn.datasets.samples_generator import make_blobs

##############################################################################
# Generate sample data
np.random.seed(0)

batch_size = 45
centers = [[1, 1], [-1, -1], [1, -1]]
n_clusters = len(centers)
X, labels_true = make_blobs(n_samples=3000, centers=centers, cluster_std=0.7)

##############################################################################
# Compute clustering with Means

k_means = KMeans(init='k-means++', n_clusters=3, n_init=10)
k_means.fit(X)
k_means_labels = k_means.labels_
k_means_cluster_centers = k_means.cluster_centers_
k_means_labels_unique = np.unique(k_means_labels)

##############################################################################
# Plot result

colors = ['#4EACC5', '#FF9C34', '#4E9A06']
plt.figure()
plt.hold(True)
for k, col in zip(range(n_clusters), colors):
    my_members = k_means_labels == k
    cluster_center = k_means_cluster_centers[k]
    plt.plot(X[my_members, 0], X[my_members, 1], 'w',
            markerfacecolor=col, marker='.')
    plt.plot(cluster_center[0], cluster_center[1], 'o', markerfacecolor=col,
            markeredgecolor='k', markersize=6)
plt.title('KMeans')    
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

Yielding:

[image]

Comment: How do we give the dataset of 2D points for clustering in this function?

Comment: Please check the variable `X` in the line no. 14. It's simply a numpy array of a shape `(n_samples, n_dim)`.

Comment: Can we find the values in each cluster ? i.e. the data and the correspoinding centoirds ?

Comment: I suggest you to go through the code slowly, trying to debug every line. What you are trying to achieve is done in line 32 and used later in 34.